# NavigationDrawer evento en Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola tengo un problema al presionar sobre una opcion de mi navigationView (R.id.create_marker) quiero crear un marker en mi MapFragment pero no logro hacerlo, alguna sugerencia?

Codigo del MainActivity.java donde presiono la opcion del menu:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
     case R.id.create_marker:
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Crear Marker", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     // Crear marcador y mostrarlo en el mapa
     break;

   }
   return false;
   }
});
```

El codigo del MapFragment.java es el que viene por defecto al crear el layout de Google Maps, adaptado para usar Fragments.

Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con la etiqueta 'android-studio'?